# Logged into ubuntu via VNC. Windows key seems stuck

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I have an ubuntu server running vnc4server and gnome-session.

When i log in remotely using VNC, it appears that the windows key is stuck. This occurs with multiple VNC clients (ultraVNC/realVNC on windows) and I have tried from other boxes.

Having the windows key stuck effectively disables using up/down, since windows key+up and windows key+down are bound to maximizing and minimizing whatever window you are on.

Comment: Ever solved this?  I've got it too now

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a vnc server issue.

When I used [tigervnc](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc) on the server, the problem went away.